# SDWebImage and UITableViewCell with multiple UiImageViews doesn't show all images

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview, sdwebimage

I need to show multiple images in each UITableViewCell. To do that, I use SDWebImage to asynchronously download the images. I run the following code within a `configCell` method in my UITableViewCell:

```
        for (int i=0; i<allOrganizationIds.count; i++) {
            self.orgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((self.frame.size.width - 10) - (55 * position), 3, 50, 15)];
            org = [[DLOrganizationManager getInstance] organizationForId:[allOrganizationIds[i] intValue]];

            [self.orgView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:org.organizationLogoUrl] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"category-selected"] completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
                [self addSubview:self.orgView];
            }];
        }
```

The problem is that it only shows one image per cell, even when there should be three. The`complete` block only gets executed once. When scrolling the particular cell out of the view and back, all images are visible.

Why doesn't the UIImageView get updated each time an image has successfully been downloaded, even while the cell is still visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You overwrite your `orgView` property on each loop iteration, meaning that the first view you create gets deallocated shortly after the second iteration because it is not retained by anyone.

Also, every image view you add have the same frame because the position variable do not change in the scope of the for loop. You should probably make use of your `i` variable in the frame calculation.

```
for (int i=0; i<allOrganizationIds.count; i++) {
    UIImageView *orgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((self.frame.size.width - 10) - (55 * position), 3, 50, 15)];
    [self addSubview:orgView]; // The image view is then strongly retained by it's superview
    org = [[DLOrganizationManager getInstance] organizationForId:[allOrganizationIds[i] intValue]];

    [orgView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:org.organizationLogoUrl] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"category-selected"] completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
        // Do wathever you want here
        // If this view is opaque without an image in it you can play with the hidden property to acheive the same effect as if you added it as a subview here
    }];
}
```

Comment: Hi Antoine and thanks for your quick reply. It's true that I use one view that I constantly overwrite. But as I pointed out, at first, only one image is visible. When scrolling the cell out of view and back right after, all images are there.  So this seems to work. 
The frame is not the same in each iteration. The "position" variable changes all the time and moves the image on the x - axis.

Comment: @oliver did you try to move your addSubview call from the completion block to the for loop?

Comment: Also, because you don't modify your position variable in the loop and you don't keep any reference to your views, it is impossible that your subviews have different frames. When you move your cells away from the screen and come back, your cells are enqueued and dequeued by the table view and you are probably calling this method again (from the method cellForRowAtIndexPath) with a different position value, that's why you see your images appear when you scroll.

Comment: Antoine, thanks for your thoughts. I changed my code according to your suggestions (Add a UIImageView in each iteration + add it as subview outside the completed block) and it finally works.

Comment: I was afraid the cell wouldn't let loose of the UIImageView and would therefore show all added images on every other dequeued cell. But against my expectations, it seems it does.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. Worked for me.

```
    for (int i=0; i<allOrganizationIds.count; i++) 
    {
                self.orgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((self.frame.size.width - 10) - (55 * position), 3, 50, 15)];

                org = [[DLOrganizationManager getInstance] organizationForId:[allOrganizationIds[i] intValue]];

                NSURL *ImgURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[org.organizationLogoUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];    

                [self.orgView sd_setImageWithURL:ImgURL placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"category-selected"] completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) 
                {


                    [self addSubview:self.orgView];

                }];
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your approach sped up the image loading process. But the behaviour of the cells didn't change.